# Custom storage for FLENS

Tags: c++, matrix

In [FLENS](http://apfel.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/FLENS/index.html) I want to implement "custom" storage (that is, to be able to provide the pointer to actual data and to be in charge of the memory management for the storage).

A matrix that manages its buffer is defined like this, for example:

```
typedef flens::GeMatrix<flens::FullStorage<double, flens::ColMajor> >  M;
```

Later, one can use the matrices like this:

```
M m1;
M m2;
M m3;
/* initialise the matrices */
m3 = m1 * m2;
```

To do the same thing with a matrix type that gives access to internal buffer one may implement, say, `GhostStorage` just the way [FullStorage](http://www.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/FLENS/flens/storage/fullstorage/fullstorage.html) is implemented, with the addition of an `init()` method that allows setting the internal pointer (full implementation is too long to paste here):

```
void
init(IndexType numRows, IndexType numCols,
      IndexType firstRow = I::defaultIndexBase,
      IndexType firstCol = I::defaultIndexBase,
      ElementType *p_data = NULL )
{
  _data = p_data;
  _numRows = numRows;
  _numCols = numCols;
  _firstRow = firstRow;
  _firstCol = firstCol;
  ASSERT(_numRows>=0);
  ASSERT(_numCols>=0);
}
```

After defining types like this:

```
typedef flens::GhostStorage<double, flens::ColMajor> GhostEng;
class MGhost : public flens::GeMatrix<GhostEng>
{
    public:
    void
    init(IndexType numRows, IndexType numCols,
    IndexType firstRow,
    IndexType firstCol,
    ElementType *p_data = NULL )
  {
    engine().init(numRows,numCols,firstRow,firstCol,p_data);
  }

};
```

I would expect that same operation as above should be possible:

```
MGhost mg1;
MGhost mg2;
MGhost mg3;
/* initialise the matrices using the init() method */
mg3 = mg1 * mg2;
```

However the compiler complains in this case:

> no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const
>   flens::MatrixClosure >,
>   flens::GeMatrix > >' to 'const MGhost&'

FLENS author provides guidance about [implementing your custom type of matrix](http://apfel.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/FLENS/flens/examples/my-symatrix.html), but I'm using an already defined matrix type here - the [flens::GeMatrix](http://www.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/FLENS/flens/matrixtypes/general/impl/gematrix.html).

Bottom line, the question is: how does one implement a matrix in FLENS that allows manipulating the internal buffer and high level interaction like `m3 = m1 * m2`?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to write your own class, FLENS already provides the functionality:

```
typedef FullStorageView<double, ColMajor>  FSView;
typedef GeMatrix<FSView>                   GeMatrixView;
GeMatrixView  A = FSView(numRows, numCols, data, ldA);
```

Here, data is the pointer to your allocated memory. This is explained is in detail in the tutorial. Besides, there is a mailing list where questions are answered quite fast.

Comment: Hello, Jack, thanks for your answer. It has been a while since I posted this question. I will look into it and mark your answer as the correct one (or not) at that time. +1 for the info.